# Change Radio Button To Checked Or Unchecked Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my radio button

```js
$(".stayalert_checkbox").click(function(){
  alert($(this).val());
  $("#stay_alert_div").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="stay_alert_checkbox" class="stayalert_checkbox"> 

<div id="stay_alert_div" style="display:none">
  <h1>I Am in Div</h1>
</div>
```

Here On Click Radio Button Div is toggleing. So

i want to uncheck radio when div is hide. i know there is option to use checkbox but is it possible using radio.

When i tried to get value of radio it return me **"ON"**.

I tried

```
$(".stayalert_checkbox").on('click',function(){
  if($(this).prop("checked",false)){
    $(this).prop("checked",true)
    $("#stay_alert_div").toggle();
  }else{
    $(this).prop("checked",false)
    $("#stay_alert_div").toggle();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure

```js
$(".stayalert_checkbox").click(function(){
if($(this).attr('checked')){
 $(this).attr('checked',false).prop('value','off');    
 }
 else{
 $(this).attr('checked',true).prop('value','on');     
 }
  alert($(this).val());
 $("#stay_alert_div").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="stay_alert_checkbox" class="stayalert_checkbox"> 

<div id="stay_alert_div" style="display:none">
  <h1>I Am in Div</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Its Call Perfect. Thank you @Nikhil Upvote For you.. :- )

Comment: Check again my answer

Comment: i dont know why there is a downvote without a reason

Answer (score 1):

You can use a flag variable

***Stack Snippet***

```js
var isChecked = 0;
$(".stayalert_checkbox").on('click', function() {
  if (isChecked) {
    $("#stay_alert_div").hide();
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
    isChecked = 0;
  } else {
    $("#stay_alert_div").show();
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
    isChecked = 1;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="stay_alert_checkbox" class="stayalert_checkbox">

<div id="stay_alert_div" style="display:none">
  <h1>I Am in Div</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand why this answer is getting upvote as question is not related to `checkbox`

Comment: @TarangP Sorry for the delay...you can use a flag variable to get this...Updated my answer....

Comment: Now it Looks fine..!

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to use this:

```
  if($("#stay_alert_div").is(":visible")){
    $(this).prop("checked",false);
  }
```

**Demo**

```js
$(".stayalert_checkbox").click(function(){
  if($("#stay_alert_div").is(":visible")){
    $(this).prop("checked",false);
  }
  $("#stay_alert_div").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="stay_alert_checkbox" class="stayalert_checkbox"> 

<div id="stay_alert_div" style="display:none">
  <h1>I Am in Div</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Please See my question i used As you say but it not changes radio value once it is checked

Comment: @WebInfos What value are you hoping to get? because you radio has no value. Do you want to get the "checked or not checked" value?

Comment: Thank you @Carsto . i got answer given by Nikhil